# Android Library Architecture

Tags: android, database, architecture, objectbox

How to make a library which is having its own database using object-box or any other database?

My requirement is to make a module specific library which can be plug and play for Android application project.

I have tried to make it using objectbox, however it's giving me error that only one instance can be open throughout app.

Can you please suggest the work around or proper architecture using object-box or any other database?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For libraries, you have two basic options with ObjectBox:

- Put all entities in a single library. This allows transactions using all entity types.
- Individual databases per library. Each entity is tied to a data base (library), and thus may only the ObjectStore of the library puts and gets its entities. Transaction can only span entities tied to one database and its group of entities.

You can mix both approaches.

To make individual databases per library work, you need to give each library a unique database name using e.g. `BoxStoreBuilder.name(...)`.

For the sake of completeness: The [BoxStoreBuilder class](http://objectbox.io/files/objectbox-java/current/io/objectbox/BoxStoreBuilder.html) also allows to specify a directory directly, or a different base directory for a name.